# Суммировать значения из столбца

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT op.ID_procedureRef, op.ServiceCode, os.Fee_Obsolete, os.CodeType
FROM procrefcode op
JOIN servicecodefee os ON op.ServiceCode = os.ServiceCode
```

Нужно сложить поле Fee c одинаковыми Id_Procedure из таблицы servicecodefee

Comment: sum(os.Fee_Obsolete) + GROUP BY os. Id_Procedure

Answer (score 0):

SELECT op.ID_procedureRef, op.ServiceCode,  os.CodeType, SUM(os.Fee_Obsolete) AS 'sum'
FROM servicecodefee
GROUP BY op.ID_procedureRef